# Exchange of limit and series with orthogonal components

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Consider a Hilbert space $H$ with a sequence of closed orthogonal subspaces $(H_m)_m$ of $H$. For each $n$ and $m$ let $f_{n,m}\in H_m$ such that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n,m}=f_m$ exists.

Under what circumstances do we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^\infty f_{n,m}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n,m},
$$
assuming the series occuring converge? I feel like there should be a way to exploit the orthogonality of the summands in the series.

Answer (score 0):

You want
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^\infty f_{n,m}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty f_{m}.
$$
So let us check:
$$
\Big\|\sum_{m=1}^\infty f_{n,m}-\sum_{m=1}^\infty f_{m}\Big\|^2=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\|f_{n,m}-f_m\|^2.
$$
So you see that even uniform convergence is not enough. You need the convergence to accelerate with $m$ so that the series on the right goes to zero with $n$.